# Understanding comprehension sets

Tags: python, json, dictionary-comprehension

Ok so I got this code :

```
class ApiCall(object):

    def __init__(self, url):
        self.url = url

    def call(self):
        call = requests.get(self.url)
        response = call.content.decode('utf-8')
        result = json.loads(response)
        return result


class IncomeSources(object):

    def __init__(self, result):
        self.result = result

    def all(self):
            #This is the dict comprehension
            #return {(slot['accountLabelType'], slot['totalPrice']) for slot in self.result}

            for slot in self.result:

                return (slot['accountLabelType'], slot['totalPrice'])

def main():
            url = ('https://datafeed/api/')
            api_result = ApiCall(url).call()
            target = IncomeSources(api_result).all()
            print(target)


main()
```

The result with a regular for on a function, returns this wich is not desired, as it only returns the pair of the first object :

```
('Transport', 888)
```

But with the dict comprehension, it returns all slot pairs of all the json objects on that json response ( that is cool ) Why the dict comprehension grabs all the pairs and the regular for is not ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why the dict comprehension grabs all the pairs and the regular for is not ?

What happens when you loop over something and have a return statement in the loop is that as soon as a return statement is encountered, that value (and only that value) is returned.

The dict comprehension first constructs the entire dictionary which then gets returned as a whole to the caller.

This has less to do with the comprehension and more with the return statement. Compare:

```
>>> def foo():
...     for i in range(5):
...         return i
...
>>> foo()
0
```

With:

```
>>> def foo():
...     return list(range(5))
...
>>> foo()
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```